# Absorption spectrum nitrogen

Tags: optics, absorption

After a couple of hours of searching I cant find the absorpion spectrum of nitrogen in UV-Vis range (350-450 nm is what im looking for).

Could anybody be so nice as to help me out?

To specify I'm talking about molecular nitrogen.

-G. Wesseling

Ps

I'm sorry for any broken or incorrect english, I'm still learning.

Comment: @CountTo10 I googled for about 2 hours including some image searches, but all I could find were sectra of NO2 and not N2. Now I will admit I'm not the best at using google so I is well in the realm of posibilities that I missed something.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I'm quite new here and don't really understand everything yet. But I'm sure that will come with time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nitrogen is transparent in that region (up to vacuum-UV). A wavelength of 350 nm corresponds to 3.55 eV, much less than the ionization energy of N$_2$.

Comment: That could very well explain why I can't find any spectra. Thanks for the awnser.

Comment: @G.Wesseling Here is something (the green line), 120 to 190 nm. For longer wavelengths, there is no absorption. http://www.photonics.com/images/Web/Articles/2014/10/6/UV_Deuterium.png

Comment: Does this mean you can ionize air with a deuterium lamp?

Comment: I would've preferred a graph.